# Rubymine can't recognize ruby file

Tags: ruby, rubymine

The file attendance_statistics_controller.rb can't be recognized as a ruby file. All other files can and when i change the name to anything else this one can aswell. It has nothing to do with the length of the filename.

[image]

The image on top shows how the ruby file is recognized as a textfile. Changing the name does the trick as shown on the one on the bottom.

[image]

Is it a bug in the application or is there something to do about it?

Comment: yes ;) it has been like this for half a year and many attempts to solve the problem has not succeded.

Comment: I would say it's safe to say this is a bug.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The file name has been registered as being a .txt file

To fix this:

1. Go to Rubymine | Preferences | Editor | filetypes.
2. Find the Text file type in the list of recognized filetypes and click it.
3. Then browse the registered patterns in the box just below and find the file name.
4. Click it and remove it with the minus(-) button.
5. Apply changes.

Comment: Completely weird behavior :/

Comment: I had added the ruby file as 'text' so I had to select text in the file type and remove the file name from it's registered pattern.

Comment: @tamrock Thanks a lot. This saved me hours of painful workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the file type icon in your screenshot, I guess you have accidentally enabled the **[Mark as Plain Text](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/2016.3/excluding-files-from-project.html?search=exclu#d497995e60) feature** upon the file. Marking the file as plain text is accessible from the file's context menu and normally it can be used to prevent Rubymine from navigating and completing the code inside the file.

Right click the file and **choose the "Mark as Ruby" item** to make Rubymine recognize it as ruby code again.

Comment: This looks like the best answer. Solving this one specific issue in the simplest way, and explaining what the issue is. (could use a screenshot or two, tho).

Comment: This solution worked when Rubymine | Preferences | Editor | filetypes did not show *.rb recognized as a plain text recognized file type. Simple and easy!